# GATE - How to create a new annotation SET?

Tags: gate

I am starting to learn GATE. I created an annotation with features but I would like to put it in a new annotation set.

Can someone please tell me how to do it with JAPE?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question - do you mean you've created an annotation in one set and want to copy it to another, or simply that you want to change which annotation set your JAPE grammar uses to create its output annotations?

Comment: I have created an annotation already, but it is in the default annotation set. What I want is to create a new annotation set (called "Key"), and put my new annotation in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/mailman/message/5348688/ and http://osdir.com/ml/ai.gate.general/2005-04/msg00052.html.
They said that a JAPE rule can't refer to more than one annotation set. These annotation sets are defined in the PR runtime parameters (outputASName, inputASName).
--> So I guess that if I want my annotation to belong to a "Key" annotation set, I should put "Key" in outputASName of my Jape transducer.
Thanks for your help Ian =)